# Call php function in backend of module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, ajax, custom-field

I am trying to call a php function from the backend of a module (I'm using a custom form field). `com_ajax` does not work because it pulls the current menu item, which doesn't exist since it is not being called from a menu.

I have tried linking to a php file directly but that will not work because `defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');` is needed for security purposes.

I have also tried using `JURI::base() . 'index.php?option=mod_myMod&task=myPhpFunction';` for my AJAX request URL while having the code block below defined before my helper class in the module's `helper.php` but just get a `404 (Component not found.)` error:

```
$taskInput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$task = $taskInput->get('task');

if ($task == "importData") {
    ModPropertySearchHelper::importDataAjax();
}
```

I could create a separate component to handle this. However, that just feels weird and is a problem `com_ajax` tried to solve, so I would rather not do that.

Is there a way I could override `ajax.php` in order to support being called from a module's backend? I wouldn't want to replace it in case of updates and such.

Or is there a better solution to my problem?

Comment: What do you mean from a "module's backend"? Are you referring to a module in the Joomla backend (admin panel)?

Comment: The part of the admin panel where you can configure various settings of a module. Where the form fields specified in the module's XML file would show up.

I am using a custom form field for this module which needs access to a PHP function in order to send user-provided data to the database.

Comment: Ahh I see. Not tried this before. Maybe try using `index.php?option=com_modules&task=myFunction`....note the `com_modules` as this is the component being used

Comment: I just tried doing that and got back a response with a bunch of html that appeared to be the `basic` module page for my module, but with no form fields or content.

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact problem that you are trying to solve? Why are you interested for a menu item id - how is it involved with the ajax results in the backend of the module?

Comment: @FFrewin I wanted a user to be able load records from a spreadsheet into a database. The built in file select field did not allow me to do that. I eventually made a modified copy of the built-in ajax component to let my module make php queries from the administrative side of Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

For security, there are several measures in Joomla that prevent direct access to scripts.

So, you have to follow Joomla good practices to take advantage of Joomla CMS.

To execute inside Joomla, you have to create a component, a module or a plugin.

If you are looking to implement an Ajax query, then you have to create a plugin for com_ajax.

**Using Joomla Ajax Interface**

> A slim, extensible component to act as an entry point for HTTP
>   requests for stand alone modules and plugins, thus allowing for the
>   potential of Ajax functionality in them. Com_ajax is generally used
>   when you are not the developer of the component that the module or
>   plugin is interacting with.

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

Comment: Yes, I would like to use com_ajax, but am unable to due to how it works. It uses the current menu item to append to the url it creates. However, since I'm calling it from the admin configuration side of joomla, that menu item doesn't exist and it gives me an error. That is why I asked if there is a way to override ajax.php (where com_ajax resides). Or if there was some other way to do this without creating a separate component/module/plug-in/etc. to use as an intermediary (which seems to be the main benefit of com_ajax being included in core of joomla).

Comment: For a little more detail, here is ajax.php of `com_ajax` on github: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_ajax/ajax.php Line 56 is where it fails for me. It is similar to [this issue](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/5930) but I can't see a way to add a `Itemid` to my com_ajax request so that it will use it instead of doing that module check.

Comment: It is not an issue. You must follow the API definition. If you call an API that requires an Itemid, just create a menu item to locate a the target following the route definition. Even if you are running from a backend, you can call any Url via Ajax.

Comment: com-ajax doesn't accept an Itemid. Can you have a form on the admin configuration be tied to a menu item?

Comment: No, backend site is oriented to a single menu of components and modules

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this module would allow you to paste in php, but I have not tried it myself.

But as Anibal says. If you are going to be using Ajax and need to interact with Joomla, you should use com_ajax and develop it yourself.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/blank-module

Comment: Interesting module, but it is for modifying how a module looks/works on the front-end of a joomla site and I need something that will let me execute a php function from an ajax call in the back-end (the admin configuration part of a module).

Comment: Sounds like you need to get your hands dirty and code this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm creating a separate component right now to do this. :(

Comment: Hopefully you are using our http://www.component-creator.com to save you some time :-)